# Is there a proper name for yymmdd format?

Tags: date

When I'm trying to talk to developers about using the `yymmdd` format, is there an easy way to refer to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try by using ISO 8601:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: Although, from the wikipedia article itself: ISO 8601:2000 allowed truncation (by agreement), where leading components of a date or time are omitted. Notably, this allowed two-digit years to be used and the ambiguous formats YY-MM-DD and YYMMDD. **This provision was removed in ISO 8601:2004**.

Comment: I'm not opposed to using YYYYMMDD so that may work. Mainly just trying to drill into my guys to that they should be listing the year first for ordering reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A date in the filename with the ddmmyy format is not as useful as the truncated version of the ISO 8901 (yymmdd) format.  The yymmdd format has many advantages esp re sort order of files, particularly if the date string is sequenced thoughtfully within the other parts of the filename.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35336869)